# Electrical circuit analyses: coil and capacitor in series

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, passive-networks, coil, math

I've a series circuit of a coil and a capacitor, in between those components we've a switch that will close when \$t=0\$. We can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{U}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=-\text{U}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{U}'_\text{C}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\\
\\
\text{U}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\text{I}'_\text{L}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\\
\\
\text{I}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\\
\end{cases}\space\space\space\space\space\therefore\space\space\space\space\space\frac{1}{\text{C}}\cdot\text{I}\left(t\right)=-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}''\left(t\right)\tag1
$$

Using Laplace transform:

$$\begin{align}
\text{I}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\text{s}\cdot\text{I}\left(0\right)+\text{I}'\left(0\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\text{L}\cdot\text{s}}\tag2\\
\text{U}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{1}{\text{C}\cdot\text{s}}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{s}\cdot\text{I}\left(0\right)+\text{I}'\left(0\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\text{L}\cdot\text{s}}+\text{C}\cdot\text{U}_\text{C}\left(0\right)\right\}\tag3\\
\text{U}_\text{L}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\text{s}\cdot\text{L}\cdot\frac{\text{s}\cdot\text{I}\left(0\right)+\text{I}'\left(0\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\text{L}\cdot\text{s}}-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}\left(0\right)\tag4
\end{align}$$

Well, I know that:

1. $$\text{U}_\text{C}\left(0\right)=200\tag5$$
2. $$\pi\sqrt{\text{C}\cdot\text{L}}<10\cdot10^{-6}=10^{-5}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{C}\cdot\text{L}<\frac{10^{-10}}{\pi^2}\tag6$$

**How can I find the value of \$\text{C}\$ and \$\text{L}\$ using the things I know?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the frequency and the initial condition left one parameter missing in the [LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).

The standard LC curcuit initial condition and oscilating frequency parameters are, here assuming the initial current is zero, and the voltage is maximum:
$$
\omega_0=\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}\\
I(0)=-I_0 cos(\phi)=0\\
V(0)=\omega_0 L I_0 sin(\phi)=\omega_0 L I_0
$$

Evaluating:
$$
\frac{\pi}{10^{-5}}<\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}\\
\frac{\pi}{10^{-5}}LI_0<\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}LI_0=200
$$

Hence, both the L and C values cannot be calculated for the equality case.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Second in the first line of your answer you say: RL circuit, but it is a LC circuit :). Third how did you get: $$\frac{\pi}{10^{-5}}LI_0<\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}LI_0=200$$

Comment: Lol. Well the \$U_C(0)=200\$ in the paragraph, assuming \$V=U\$. Ref. Wiki.